# Give a counter example

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was considering the possibility of writing primes (except 2 and 3) in the form 2n + 3 for some positive integer n. Is it always possible ?

Comment: This just asks whether every prime $p>3$ is odd, i.e., of the form $2m+1$ with $m>1$ - which is clearly true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is always possible. Indeed a prime number $p>3$ is odd and therefore can be written $p=2m+1$ with $m > 1$ (since $p>3$). Then $p=2(m-1+1)+1=2(m-1)+3=2n+3$ with $n=m-1$ a positive integer.

Note that this result is very general and does not help to distinguish prime numbers since it is true for every odd number greater than 3.

Answer (score 0):

*Every* odd number $p$ greater than 4 can be written in the form $2n + 3$; just choose $n = \frac{p-3}{2}$. So this statement is certainly true for all primes other than 2 and 3.